# Is it safe to use a form to store html code inside a database using PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, security, pdo

Right now I'm using a form to store html input, and then storing them in the database using PDO and mysql. The website then uses these inserted values to display parts of the site. Is that safe? Is there a better solution?  What are the possible security implications?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/ - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting

Comment: thanks, looking at it now

Comment: There is nothing wrong with *storing HTML*. The problem is in emitting the HTML *without escaping in the appropriate context*. SQL Injection is not about HTML (or any data *actually* stored), but about allowing invalid/arbitrary/malicious SQL to run in an unexpected query "shape".

Comment: This is essentially how Content Management Systems work.

Comment: i c, thanks for your comment barmar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Is that safe? Yes,** so long as you're using something like [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) when you actually display it to the user.

Is it the best solution? Perhaps not. But hardly the worst.